# Blueimp Jquery fileupload plugin not uploading all files on mobile (works well on desktop)

Tags: jquery-mobile, file-upload, jquery-plugins, jquery-file-upload

I'm using [Jquery Fileupload plugin](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload)  to upload files to server. While it works well on the desktop. It doesn't work as expected on the mobile browser. Of the several images selected for upload, only few images get uploaded, the remaining images get uploaded once the user touches or swipes across the screen. In essence an additional physical touch or scroll on the mobile screen is required to complete the image upload. Please [click here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=85vcIBOpI-4) to see the video.

Can someone please suggest how I can get all the images to upload without having to physically touch or scroll on the mobile screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer may help others in the future.
In the plugin look for the file 'jquery.fileupload-ui.js' and change autoupload option from 'false' to 'true.